# Таблица у которой ячейки с одинаковой шириной и высотой

Tags: javascript, css

Можно ли сделать таблицу без js, у которой ячейки одинаковой ширины и высоты?
при этом таблица динамическая, изначально не известно сколько будет ячеек

```css
.container{
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
table{
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
  text-align:center;
}
td{
  border: 1px solid #E7ECF2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td>1</td>
           <td>2</td>
           <td>3</td>
           <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>5</td>
           <td>6</td>
           <td>7</td>
           <td>8</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jouhntv3/
или это нужно делать с js и вычислять ширину?

Comment: А таблица какого размера должна быть?

Comment: @DiD, может быть 3х3, 3х4, 3х5 и т.д. Кстати изначально известно только номер числа ячеек в ряду, и по этому номеру в цикле формируются ячейки

Comment: <td style="height: {{ 100 / $size }}%">{{ $n }}</td> так задаётся высота, но высота такая и осталась как и была

Comment: $size - это количество колонок я ряду

Comment: height: 25% не задаёт высоту у ячейки, если в ряду 4 ячейки

Comment: Какой код генерирует таблицу? Это сервер или браузер?

Answer (score 2):

Вы имеете в виду так?

JS тут только для добавления ячеек. Если таблица генерируется на сервере, содержимое тега `<style>` должно генерироваться вместе с таблицей.

```js
const table = document.querySelector('table');
const style = document.querySelector('body style');

function addCol() {
  table.querySelectorAll('tr')
    .forEach(tr => tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td')));
  setStyle();
}

function addRow() {
  let tr = document.createElement('tr');
  table.querySelectorAll('table tr:nth-child(1) td')
    .forEach(() => tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td')));
  table.appendChild(tr);
  setStyle();
}

function setStyle() {
  style.innerHTML =
    `td { width: min( calc(100vh / ${table.querySelectorAll('tr').length} - 1px), calc(100vw / ${table.querySelectorAll('table tr:nth-child(1) td').length} - 1px) );
        height: min( calc(100vh / ${table.querySelectorAll('tr').length} - 1px), calc(100vw / ${table.querySelectorAll('table tr:nth-child(1) td').length} - 1px) ); }`;
}

function showCSS(){
  alert(style.innerHTML);
  }
```

```css
button {
  position: absolute;
}

button:nth-child(2) {
  top: 1.5rem;
}

button:nth-child(3) {
  top: 3rem;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

table {
  top: 0;
  max-width: 100vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-height: 100vh;
  border-collapse: collapse;

}
```

```html
<button onclick="addCol()">Add col</button>
<button onclick="addRow()">Add row</button>
<button onclick="showCSS()">Show CSS</button>
<style>
  td {
    width: calc( 100vh / 3 - 1px);
    height: calc( 100vh / 3 - 1px);
  }
  table {
    height: 100vh;
  }
</style>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: это не то, добавь ячейку и ячейки уже не ровные, https://jsfiddle.net/a6tb5sgj/

Comment: Не понимаю куда именно вы хотите добавить ячейку?

Comment: у вас таблица 3х3, https://jsfiddle.net/a6tb5sgj/ здесь я добавил ячейки в ваш код, и ячейки перестали быть одинаковой ширины и высоты

Comment: вы поставили table{ height: 100vh;} это вообще не подходит для моего вышеприведённого кода, где есть .container, для чего ставить высоту на всю высоту экрана? у таблицы есть родитель .container, у которого может быть разная ширина, таблица на всю ширину контейнера, и ячейки должны быть при любом размере контейнера, должны быть одинаковой ширины и высоты?

Comment: кароче я понял что без js не обойтись :)

Comment: получилось сделать так: <td style="padding-bottom:25%"><div>1</div></td>
и div position absolute

Comment: блин всё-равно не ровно через css

Comment: <td style="padding-bottom:25%"><div>1</div></td> и div position absolute, кстати этот вариант работает, просто padding-top  был прописан большой, сейчас его убрал и выровнялось нормально, благодарю за ваш вариант решения

Comment: Вот сейчас конечный результат. Потрем комменты.

Answer (score 2):

Есть старый, но немного костыльный способ делать квадратные блоки на одном лишь `css`, используя особенность вертикального паддинга в процентах (берётся от **ширины** родителя). Правда в таком случае контент ячейки придётся абсолютить.

```css
*,*before,*after{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container{
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
table{
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
  text-align:center;
}
td{
  border: 1px solid #E7ECF2;
  position: relative;
}
td:before{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
td span{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td><span>1</span></td>
           <td><span>2</span></td>
           <td><span>3</span></td>
           <td><span>4</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td><span>5</span></td>
           <td><span>6</span></td>
           <td><span>7</span></td>
           <td><span>8</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```